# Recreating gloss from older version of Blender

Tags: shaders

I am using Blender 2.92.0 and learning from the [Andrew Price earth tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y) in Blender 2.76.

[image: Blender 2.76 gloss on earth]

Using the same steps, my lighting and/or material looks significantly different:

[image: Blender 2.92 gloss on earth]

Notice that the scattering seems different, like the roughness of the surface or the intensity of the lighting does not match up. Andrew's has a distinctive haze around the edge. I can get a more similar effect by increasing the Glossy BSDF roughness to 0.36 and giving the sun a slightly different angle, as shown below, but I'm just curious about the possible cause of the difference?

[image: Earth with more gloss roughness]

Here's the setup for the original images above:

[image: Blender 2.76 shader]
[image: Blender 2.92 shader]

I redid the first few minutes of the tutorial twice to make sure I hadn't missed anything.

In general, do shader setups tend to produce different results across different versions of Blender? In other words, is there some sort of "hidden state" that does not carry over, either due to rendering engine changes or modifications to the shader components themselves?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's possible that the distribution function you're using differs, or some changes in cycles make this the case.  If you want to be sure, you can grab the old version of blender and recreate it.

Comment: Or it could be filmic color transform, I suppose

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I downloaded Blender 2.76 and the gloss looked more natural / smooth right away. Oddly if I switch my color transform from Filmic to Standard in the newer Blender, it becomes even more off, and I have to increase the Roughness to ~0.4 to get a better approximation of the default 0.2 value in v2.76.